# Using cforms to create a post?

Tags: database, wordpress, post

I am creating a job board site using wordpress where a user will fill out a form and then the form data will be posted to the site (aka, it will create the job post). I have used cforms to create the form, which looks fine, but isn't working. Is it possible to take the form data and create a post from it? Or take the form data, put it into a database, and then call the database entries and create posts from them? I am not really sure how to approach this. Is there a better way to do this than using cforms?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using entries instead of forms, I would use:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-field-template/

This gives the possibility to create the metaboxes you need and present them associated to the right template.